# typescript cannot find module which is defined in declaration file of npm linked local project

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsc, typescript2.0

I have a module Foo which has a declaration file `builds/declarations.d.ts`, which is mentioned in `package.json`:

```
'types' : './builds/declarations.d.ts'
```

The declaration file declares things like so:

```
declare module '@my/module/lib/models/Base' {
    export default class Base { 
        test():void;
    }
}
```

Then in module Bar I have module Foo linked with `npm link`. And it has files trying to access classes from Foo:

```
import Base from "@my/module/lib/models/Base";
```

however the compiler give this error:

```
Cannot find module '@my/module/lib/models/Base'.
```

Note that it was working before when I temporarily had separate declaration files, so when `@my/module/lib/models/Base.d.ts` was an existing file.

But now that I have bundled all my declarations nicely into one file, and mentioned it in package.json the compiler can't find the module.

But it **does** work when I specifically add the declaration file to `tsconfig.json` like so:

```
"files": [
  "./src/index.ts",
  "./node_modules/@my/module/lib/models/declarations.d.ts"
]
```

But I thought the whole point of having it declared in package.json was that it would be picked up automatically?

Any hints what I should be doing differently to have the compiler pick up the declarations automatically?

Comment: Declaring it in package.json makes it available automatically, BUT for other packages that depend on this one and install it using `npm install your-package`. The correct way to compile your package is to add these declarations to `files` in `tsconfig.json` as you did, or include it in compilation in some other way.